# Avoid IntelliJ to auto create @Qualifier annotation

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

When i am doing the Alt+Insert thing in IntelliJ to use an autowired Dependency, IntelliJ automatically creates a field like this:

```
@Qualifier("beanName")
@Autowired
private Bean bean;
```

Does someone know if there is the possibility to let IntelliJ stop writing @Qualifier annotation?

Comment: What exactly are you typing? If I have a field, put the cursor above it, type "@Au" it shows the completion popup, so then all I have to do is <enter> to make it complete to "@Autowired". In that case it does not automatically add @Qualifier(...). (Using IntelliJ 14.0 Ultimate Edition).

Answer (score 1):

> Does someone know if there is the possibility to let IntelliJ stop writing @Qualifier annotation?

The short answer is you can't. The `@Autowire Dependency` code generation action does not use an editable File Template.

The long answer is you can prevent it from being inserted... IDEA will only insert that if there is no ambiguity as to the bean being used. For example, if I have one and only one bean of the type `UniqueBean` defined in my Spring Context Configuration, IDEA will insert the following:

```
@Autowired
private UniqueBean uniqueBean;
```

As soon as there are multiple instances of a bean type *across all the "Spring Application" configurations configured for the module's Spring Facet*, IDEA will want to qualify it and therefore insert the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Comment: The interesting thing is, that there is not. This behavior is only when I use the injection assistant to inject a JpaRepository. Maybe IntelliJ thinks I want to inject the interface JpaRepository, not my implementation.